# mysql sort category according to parent id

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the table structure

```
id   parent_id   name
1    0           BMW
2    0           Mercedez
3    0           Porsche
4    1           3 Series
5    2           E60
6    1           5 Series
7    3           Cayenne
```

How can i show the table as

```
BMW
3 Series
5 Series
Mercedez
E60
Porsche
Cayenne
```

The above table shows ascending id followed by parent_id associated with that id, then go to second id and so on. I need in a single query, is it possible to do as such?

Comment: agree, i am continuing others work, i have no flexibility of changing mysql, it is all fixed

Comment: Not getting why u want it

Comment: the problem is that i must use SQL and cannot depend on programming language

Comment: it was -5 downvoted at start, atleast -1 now, i guess people are way too 'smart' to answer dummy question like this

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  name,
  CASE WHEN parent_id = 0 THEN id ELSE parent_id END AS Sort
FROM
  cars
ORDER BY
  Sort,
  id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b05f/3

---

### EDIT:

Given that this answer keeps getting upvotes, I revisited the question and found a flaw. If, for some reason, the parent has a higher ID than the child, the ordering gets messed up. The above query only works if the parent ID is a lower number than all the children.

To demonstrate the problem, imagine the table looked like this:

```
id   parent_id   name
8    0           BMW
2    0           Mercedez
3    0           Porsche
4    8           3 Series
5    2           E60
6    8           5 Series
7    3           Cayenne
```

Notice now that `BMW` has an `id` of **8** instead of **1**. The result will look like this:

```
Mercedez
E60
Porsche
Cayenne
3 Series
5 Series
BMW
```

Notice above that **BMW** shows up at the bottom of the list, *after* its children! This is because the secondary sorting orders by `id`, and if the parent ID happens to be higher than any children, the parent may not show up on top of the children.

This query will solve that problem:

```
SELECT
  name
FROM
  cars
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN parent_id = 0 THEN id ELSE parent_id END, -- another way of writing it: IFNULL(NULLIF(parent_id, 0), id)
  parent_id,
  id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d6d73/3

To explain what's going on here, you first order by the parent row's `id` field and the children rows' `parent_id` field. If you order by that, all the children will be grouped up with their parent, and the overall list will be ordered by the parent's `id` field.

But that doesn't set the sorting within the families, so the parent could show up anywhere within the family (the parent could show up at the top, or it could be in the middle, or it could be last).

That's where the other two sorting fields come in. The second field sorts by `parent_id`, and the parent row's `parent_id` field is always `0`. Safely assuming that your ID fields are always positive, this means that the parent record will always show up on top within the family. The rest of the children will all have the same value for `parent_id`, so the third sorting field orders the children within the family by their `id` field. This could also be changed to `name`, depending on how you want the children sorted.

Comment: very well done, you really helped me instead like others who criticized so much

Comment: @cicakman: I agree...I didn't think it was a bad question at all. Not sure why you got so much criticism.

Comment: Thanks! Your updated solution was the right way to do it :)

Comment: 2018 and this is still helping!