# Displaying Categories & Sub Categories In Order

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

On my table it displays all the categories from my database

As you can see in image below there is a `category id` with 1

And there are two category with `parent category id` with `1` also

> **Question:** If any categories have a parent category id that matches
>   another category  have them display under that category.

Currently Table Looks Like

[image]

Model

```
public function get_categories() {
    $data = array();

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'category');
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $result) {
            $data[] = array(
                'category_id' => $result['category_id'],
                'parent_category_id' => $result['parent_category_id'],
                'name' => $result['name'],
                'url' => $result['url'],
                'status' => $result['status'],
                'date_added' => $result['date_added'],
                'category_delete' => anchor('admin/category/delete/' . $result['category_id'], 'Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-block')),
                'category_edit' => anchor('admin/category/update/' . $result['category_id'], 'Edit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block'))
            );
        }

    } else {
        return false;
    }

    return $data;   
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

class Category extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->dynamic->set_title('Category');

        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'active' => '',
            'href' => anchor('admin/dashboard', 'Home')
        );

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'active' => 'class="active"',
            'href' => 'Category'
        );

        $this->load->library('table');

        $template = array(
        'table_open'            => '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">',

        'thead_open'            => '<thead>',
        'thead_close'           => '</thead>',

        'heading_row_start'     => '<tr>',
        'heading_row_end'       => '</tr>',
        'heading_cell_start'    => '<th>',
        'heading_cell_end'      => '</th>',

        'tbody_open'            => '<tbody>',
        'tbody_close'           => '</tbody>',

        'row_start'             => '<tr>',
        'row_end'               => '</tr>',
        'cell_start'            => '<td>',
        'cell_end'              => '</td>',

        'row_alt_start'         => '<tr>',
        'row_alt_end'           => '</tr>',
        'cell_alt_start'        => '<td>',
        'cell_alt_end'          => '</td>',

        'table_close'           => '</table>'
        );

        $this->table->set_heading(array('Category ID', 'Parent ID', 'Category Name', 'Category URL', 'Category Status', 'Category Date Added', 'Category Delete', 'Category Edit'));

        $this->table->set_template($template);

        $data['categories'] = $this->table->generate($this->get_categories());

        $data['header'] = Modules::run('admin/common/header/index');
        $data['footer'] = Modules::run('admin/common/footer/index');
        $data['timeout'] = Modules::run('admin/common/timeout/index');
        $data['navbar'] = Modules::run('admin/common/navbar/index');

        $this->load->view('template/catalog/category_view', $data);

    }

    public function get_categories() {
        $data = array();

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'category');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            foreach ($query->result_array() as $result) {
                $data[] = array(
                    'category_id' => $result['category_id'],
                    'parent_category_id' => $result['parent_category_id'],
                    'name' => $result['name'],
                    'url' => $result['url'],
                    'status' => $result['status'],
                    'date_added' => $result['date_added'],
                    'category_delete' => anchor('admin/category/delete/' . $result['category_id'], 'Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-block')),
                    'category_edit' => anchor('admin/category/update/' . $result['category_id'], 'Edit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block'))
                );
            }

        } else {
            return false;
        }

        return $data;   
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ` sub categories with parent_category_id 1 should display underneath`?? Do you want to style in a manner that it should give a feel that they are sub part of above like some indentation ???

Comment: If any categories have a parent category id that matches another category have them display under that category.

Comment: So you mean, all those sub child should be under parent they belong too keeping the UI same as you have.Just use order_by instead as said by @senthil below

If that's not the case let me know more on this

Answer (score 0):

Inside get categories function, add the order by call.

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'category');
    $this->db->order_by('parent_category_id asc , category_id asc');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Did not work did not display them under correct category

Comment: First line modify to : $this->db->select("each-fielnames-commaseparated,  CASE WHEN parent_category_id = 0 THEN category_id ELSE parent_category_id END AS Sort");    Then in the 3 rd line above modify to : $this->db->order_by('Sort', 'category_id')

Comment: Ref: Same scenario: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17147500/mysql-sort-category-according-to-parent-id

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I have had to use multiple foreach loop in model.

```
<?php

class Category_model extends CI_Model {

    public function get_categories() {
        $data = array();

        // 1st level category

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'category');
        $this->db->where('parent_id', '0');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

            foreach ($query->result_array() as $result) {

                $data[] = array(
                    'name' => $result['name'],
                    'url' => $result['url'],
                    'status' => ($result['status']) ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled',
                    'date_added' => $result['date_added'],
                    'category_delete' => anchor('admin/category/delete/' . $result['category_id'], 'Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-block')),
                    'category_edit' => anchor('admin/category/update/' . $result['category_id'], 'Edit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block'))
                );

                // 2nd level category

                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'category');
                $this->db->where('sub_id', '0');
                $this->db->where('parent_id', $result['category_id']);
                $query = $this->db->get();

                foreach ($query->result_array() as $result) {

                    $parent_category_name = $this->get_parent_category_name($result['parent_id']);

                    $data[] = array(
                        'name' => '<b>' . $parent_category_name->name . '</b>' . ' &gt; '. $result['name'],
                        'url' => $result['url'],
                        'status' => ($result['status']) ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled',
                        'date_added' => $result['date_added'],
                        'category_delete' => anchor('admin/category/delete/' . $result['category_id'], 'Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-block')),
                        'category_edit' => anchor('admin/category/update/' . $result['category_id'], 'Edit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block'))
                    );

                    // 3rd level category

                    $this->db->select('*');
                    $this->db->from($this->db->dbprefix . 'category');
                    $this->db->where('sub_id', $result['category_id']);
                    $query = $this->db->get();

                    foreach ($query->result_array() as $result) {

                        $parent_category_name = $this->get_parent_category_name($result['parent_id']);
                        $sub_category_name = $this->get_parent_category_name($result['sub_id']);

                        $data[] = array(
                            'name' => '<b>' . $parent_category_name->name . '</b>' . ' &gt; '. '<b>' . $sub_category_name->name . '</b>' . ' &gt; '. $result['name'],
                            'url' => $result['url'],
                            'status' => ($result['status']) ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled',
                            'date_added' => $result['date_added'],
                            'category_delete' => anchor('admin/category/delete/' . $result['category_id'], 'Delete', array('class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-block')),
                            'category_edit' => anchor('admin/category/update/' . $result['category_id'], 'Edit', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-block'))
                        );

                    }

                }
            }

            return $data;
    
        } else {

            return false;

        }   
    }

    public function get_parent_category_name($parent_category_id) {
        $this->db->where('category_id', $parent_category_id);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'category');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->row();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function get_sub_category_name($sub_category_id) {
        $this->db->where('category_id', $sub_category_id);
        $query = $this->db->get($this->db->dbprefix . 'category');

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->row();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]